# How can I set index while converting dictionary to dataframe?

Tags: python, python-3.x, pandas, dataframe, dictionary

I have a dictionary that looks like the below

```py
defaultdict(list,
        {'Open': ['47.47', '47.46', '47.38', ...],
         'Close': ['47.48', '47.45', '47.40', ...],
         'Date': ['2016/11/22 07:00:00', '2016/11/22 06:59:00','2016/11/22 06:58:00', ...]})
```

My purpose is to convert this dictionary to a dataframe and to set the 'Date' key values as the index of the dataframe.

I can do this job by the below commands

```py
df = pd.DataFrame(dictionary, columns=['Date', 'Open', 'Close'])
df.index = df.Date
```

Output:

```
               Date                  Date    Open   Close
2016/11/22 07:00:00   2016/11/22 07:00:00   47.47   47.48
2016/11/22 06:59:00   2016/11/22 06:59:00   47.46   47.45
2016/11/22 06:58:00   2016/11/22 06:58:00   47.38   47.38
```

but, then I have two 'Date' columns, one of which is the index and the other is the original column.

Is there any way to set index **while** converting dictionary to dataframe, without having overlapping columns like the below?

```
               Date   Close    Open
2016/11/22 07:00:00   47.48   47.47
2016/11/22 06:59:00   47.45   47.46
2016/11/22 06:58:00   47.38   47.38
```

Answer (score 42, accepted):

Use [`set_index`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/generated/pandas.DataFrame.set_index.html):

```
df = pd.DataFrame(dictionary, columns=['Date', 'Open', 'Close'])  
df = df.set_index('Date')       
print (df)
                      Open  Close
Date                             
2016/11/22 07:00:00  47.47  47.48
2016/11/22 06:59:00  47.46  47.45
2016/11/22 06:58:00  47.38  47.40
```

Or use `inplace`:

```
df = pd.DataFrame(dictionary, columns=['Date', 'Open', 'Close'])  
df.set_index('Date', inplace=True)       
print (df)
                      Open  Close
Date                             
2016/11/22 07:00:00  47.47  47.48
2016/11/22 06:59:00  47.46  47.45
2016/11/22 06:58:00  47.38  47.40
```

Another possible solution filter out `dict` by `Date` key and then set index by `dictionary['Date']`:

```
df = pd.DataFrame({k: v for k, v in dictionary.items() if not k == 'Date'}, 
                   index=dictionary['Date'], 
                   columns=['Open','Close'])  
df.index.name = 'Date'
print (df)
                      Open  Close
Date                             
2016/11/22 07:00:00  47.47  47.48
2016/11/22 06:59:00  47.46  47.45
2016/11/22 06:58:00  47.38  47.40
```

Comment: Thank you for your detailed answer! May I ask you for more explanation for the last solution? It's not easy for me to understand what is in the DataFrame() command. What do k and v stand for? Is it similar to list comprehension?

Comment: yes, it is dict comprehension, very similar as list comprehension, only output is another or changed original dict.

Answer (score 2):

If the original dictionary is not needed, then an alternative is to simply pop the `Date` key.

```py
df = pd.DataFrame(mydict, index=pd.Series(mydict.pop('Date'), name='Date'))
```

That said, I think `set_index` is the more convenient and less verbose option that can be called immediately on the newly created frame:

```py
df = pd.DataFrame(mydict).set_index('Date')
```

[image: res]